# What is a confidence threshold of 95,0% in Google Analytics Experiments?

Tags: google-analytics, a-b-testing

In Google Analytics Experiments you can *Set a confidence threshold
95.0%* (or 99,0% or 99,5%). The documentation says:

> Set a confidence threshold: The minimum confidence threshold that must be achieved before Analytics can declare a winner. The higher the threshold, the more confident you can be in the result. A higher threshold can result in Analytics taking longer to declare a winner.

I understand the words but I have no clue what that means. What is a confidence treshold of 95%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confidence threshold (or level) is a statistical term which, in a nut shell, denotes the confidence with which you can say that experiment A is better than experiment B.

It denotes the statistical significance with which you can declare the winner. You can read more about it here - http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/meancomp.htm

To reach higher confidence level, you need more data and thus google will need more time to reach 99.0% level than it require to reach 90% confidence level and thus they ask this number so they can declare winner when they achieve this confidence level.

Comment: Good link! And `statistical significance ` is a good key word.

Comment: Do you have a clue what numbers in impression that would be?

Comment: It depends on the success of the two experiments. e.g. if the conversion on one page is 10% and on the other it's just 1%, then, 99% confidence will be reached early but if the mean conversion on two pages are 9.5% and 10% respectively, then, it will take a long long time to reach 99% confidence.